# How can I omit a field when importing JSON?

Tags: json, go

How can I unmarshall json into a Go struct and omit a specific field? [The docs](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) say I can tag a field with `json: "-"` to omit it, but this doesn't appear to do anything:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var data = []byte(`{"bar": true, "baz": true}`)

type Foo struct {
    Bar bool `json: "bar"`
    Baz bool `json: "-"`
}

func main() {
    var foo Foo
    json.Unmarshal(data, &foo)

    fmt.Println(foo)
}
```

prints  `{true, true}`

If tagging the `Baz` field with `json: "-"` worked, I would expect to `{true, false}` to print. What went wrong?

[Go Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/uVjv0TR5dd)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space seems to matter:

```
Baz bool `json:"-"`
```

Prints:

```
{true false}
```

[Go](http://play.golang.org/p/U3tvJ7N9OU)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [to not export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the fields you want to omit. Note the lowercase `baz` in the struct definition:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var data = []byte(`{"bar": true, "baz": true}`)

type Foo struct {
    Bar bool
    baz bool
}

func main() {
    var foo Foo
    json.Unmarshal(data, &foo)

    fmt.Println(foo)
}
```

Prints

`{true false}`

[GO](http://play.golang.org/p/kGZsVBGXC9)